Should I use a Flatlist or just map when displaying interactive stickers using React Native?
I am using react native to add stickers similar to FB or IG stories and created this component using Pan Handler. I've tried several ways to improve performance but it starts to slow down when there are more than 50+ stickers on the screen.
I've tried other apps like Mininote (although I'm not sure if it's coded in RN) but it's still fast even if I tried adding a hundred stickers.
What I've Tried
Currently I'm using .map() but I know it's bad on performance, I've tried using Flatlist but it doesn't work on absolute positioned elements even if I imported it from react-native-gesture-handler
I have also tried using Flashlist and RecyclerListView but the problem is the same.
What could be other possible options?

Hi, welcome to SO. Please add the code you're using so others can see what the issue is. Check out [ask] when you can.

Using FlatList for a larger dataset for performance and features like infinite scroll and pull to refresh is a good practice.
Please provide the code so that other contributors can check the issue with your code.
